# Not work recyclerView setOnScrollListener after clear it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that pull up/down to load more/refresh data.
when I pull up, all things are ok.but when I clear recycler for refresh data, recyclerView setOnScrollListener not work.
thanks.

```
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            Toast.makeText(G.context, "load more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            simulateLoading();
            refreshWorkList();


        }
    });


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            page = 0;
            recyclerDatas.clear();
            adapViewWrkLst.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            initRecyclerView();
            simulateLoading();
            refreshWorkList();


        }
    });


public void initRecyclerView() {
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();

}
```

Comment: You are calling `recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners()` inside `initRecyclerView`, which is called from `onRefresh()`